# preventDefault, make changes and continue routine

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, preventdefault, stoppropagation, attachevent

I have a small site with a script that runs a query with mysql and returns me some data, including domains. These domains are generated html links and I want to change in javascript, since I can not access the part of php, but yes to the javascript and css code.

I just want you the code is run when the click event is triggered on a link. I tried to stop the execution by default and make a change, but my code does not open the page. If I remove preventDefault only works in firefox, but I have not chrome. (window.open not use, I want to change the original link).

```
var domains = document.getElementsByClassName("domain");

for(var x = 0; x < domains.length; x++){
    if(domains[x].addEventListener) {
        domains[x].addEventListener("click", changeLink, "false");
    } else if(domains[x].attachEvent) {
        domains[x].attachEvent("onclick", changeLink);
    }
}

function changeLink(evt){

    var urlOriginal = this.href;

    // If I remove preventDefault, the function runs correctly on firefox but not in chrome
    evt.preventDefault();

    if(urlOriginal != 'http://google.com') {

        urlOriginal = urlOriginal.replace(/http:\/\//g, '');

        evt.stopPropagation();

        this.href = 'http://intodns.com/' + urlOriginal;

        console.log('Okay !');

    }

    return true;
}
```

I tried several changes but none is running, not really the case.

Does anyone know the cause of malfunction? How I can fix it without window.open?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing `"false"` (string) into `addEventListener`? I assume you meant to pass `false` (boolean)?

Comment: @Tudmotu tried it omitting the false, but I saw an example in reading a blog, so I used it, I added it thinking that maybe solve my mistake. It does not work, put false or omit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try `stopPropagation` instead

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ - read more about it

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood correctly. Try using event.isPropagationStopped() ? Thank you.

Comment: instead of preventDefault method use stopPropagation. Not sure if that will work but try ti

Comment: I'll use window.open because I find the way to make this work (i´m newbie), I think it is as simple and fast. thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to redirect the user to a different link, instead of the one that is set in the `href` attribute.

Once the `click` is made, nothing will happen if you change the `href` attribute of the element. What you are looking for is redirecting the user, and this is made possible by modifying the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object which resides on `window`.

Instead of this line:

```
this.href = 'http://intodns.com/' + urlOriginal;
```

Try this:

```
window.location = 'http://intodns.com/' + urlOriginal;
```